# MVC4: Html.DropDownList not saving value to Model Entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I have created a `View` in my MVC4 application for Creating Users. In this View, a User can have a property set for either `Organization` or for `Sponsor`, but not both. My current code is correctly displaying all of the Organizations/Sponsors depending upon what is being shown based upon a Switch selection, but when I make a selection in either `DropDownList` and save the new user, all the DropDownLists return is a `Null` value for the `User`.

**Users Model (Partial):**

```
    [GridColumn(Title = "Org.", SortEnabled = true, Width = "100")]
    public int? MemberOrgId { get; set; }

    [NotMappedColumn]
    public int? SponsorOrgId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MemberOrgId")]
    [NotMappedColumn]
    public virtual MemberOrganizations Organization { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SponsorOrgId")]
    [NotMappedColumn]
    public virtual SponsorOrganizations Sponsor { get; set; }
```

**Create (VIEW):**

```
@model PROJECT.Models.Users

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/.../.../.../_AdminLayout.cshtml";
    string cancelEditUrl = "/Admin/UserController/";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "UserController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RegisteredDate)

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="checkbox" value="12345" name="Sponsor-Organization" checked class="userCreate-BSSwitch"/> 

        <div style="margin-bottom: 15px">        
            <div class="row switchOn">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MemberOrgId, "Organization")
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.DropDownList("OrganizationId", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "OrgIdDropDown" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MemberOrgId)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row switchOff">
                <dliv class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SponsorOrgId, "Sponsor")
                </dliv>
                <div class="editor-field" >
                    @Html.DropDownList("SponsorId", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SponsorIdDropDown" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SponsorOrgId)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" id="submitRow">
            <div class="btn-group ">
                <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success">Create User</button>
            </div>
            <a href="@cancelEditUrl" onclick="confirmCancel()" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>

        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(function () { $("#alert").alert('close'); }, 5000);
        $('.switchOff').addClass('hide');

    });  
    $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.onText = 'Member';
    $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.offText = 'Sponsor';
    $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.offColor = 'info';
    $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.animate = false;

    //$.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.size = 'large';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input:checkbox[name="Sponsor-Organization"]').bootstrapSwitch();
    });

    $('input:checkbox[name="Sponsor-Organization"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
        var checked = state;
        if (checked) {
            $('.switchOn').removeClass('hide');
            $('.switchOff').addClass('hide');
            $('#SponsorIdDropDown').val("");
        }
        else {
            $('.switchOff').removeClass('hide');
            $('.switchOn').addClass('hide');
            $('#OrgIdDropDown').val("");
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn-danger").click(function () {
            var cancel = confirm("Are you sure? Entered data will be lost.")
            if (cancel != true) {
                event.preventDefault(); // cancel the event
            }
        });
    });

    //$('input:checkbox[name="Sponsor-Organization"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
</script>
```

**Controller (Create GET):**

```
//
        // GET: /Admin/
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.headerTitle = "Create a User";

            ViewBag.OrganizationId = new SelectList(db.MemberOrganizations, "Id", "Name");
            ViewBag.SponsorId = new SelectList(db.SponsorOrganizations, "Id", "Name");
            Users newUser = new Users();
            newUser.RegisteredDate = DateTime.Now;
            newUser.LastVisitDate = DateTime.Now;
            newUser.ProfilePictureSrc = null;
            return View(newUser);
        }
```

**Controller (Create HTTP-Post):**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Users users)
    {
        ViewBag.headerTitle = "Create a User";

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(users.Email, "defaultPassword");

            Users user2 = db.Users.Where(u => u.Email == users.Email).FirstOrDefault();

            user2.Enabled = true;
            user2.Password = Membership.GeneratePassword(15, 7);
            user2.ForumUsername = users.Name;
            user2.RegisteredDate = DateTime.Now;
            user2.ReceiveSystemEmails = true;
            db.Entry(user2).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            string[] roleNames = new string[] { "role1", "role2", "role3" };
            System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUserToRoles(users.Email, roleNames);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

Anyone have some thoughts on the matter? I've tried a few different suggestions I found in other questions, but nothing has worked as of yet. This is my first MVC application, so I feel as if I may be overlooking something very basic.

Comment: When you say "all the DropDownLists return is a Null value for the User", you mean the properties are null for users in the controller ?
Do you have properties named OrganizationId and SponsorId in your model? Because that's where your dropdowns selection are binded in the view.

Comment: When HTTP-Post for my Controller Create() method finishes, if I have selected a value in the dropdown, the user gets created, but the appropriate field is still designated as `NULL`. I forgot that I had changed `OrganizationId` in my model to `MemberOrgID` and `SponsorId` to `SponsorOrgId`. I thought changing the `@Html.DropDownList()`'s to reference those would fix it, but now I receive: `@Html.DropDownList("MemberOrgId", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "OrgIdDropDown" })`-`There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'MemberOrgId'`

Answer (score 1):

for a field to be tied to the model it has to be in a "for" helper (except display).  try changing your drop downs like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.OrganizationId, null, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control"})

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SponsorId, null, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

assuming your users model has fields OrganizationId and SponsorId those fields will be tied to the drop down (set them on the get and the drop down will be set and the drop down value will be passed back to the controller through the post)

**Edit**

I would suggest passing your drop down list through your model.  to your model add

```
public SelectList OrganizationList { get; set; }
public SelectList SponsorList { get; set; }
```

then on your controller (in the get)

```
newUser.OranizationList = new SelectList(db.MemberOrganizations, "Id", "Name");
newUser.SponsorList = new SelectList(db.SponsorOrganizations, "Id", "Name");
```

then on your view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.MemberOrgId, Model.OrganizationList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: I've listed my relevant `Users` Model fields above. I tried `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.MemberOrgId, null, string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "OrgIdDropDown" })`, but my View fails to load saying, `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'MemberOrgId'.`?

Comment: i added an edit on how to pass the drop down list through your model instead of the view data/bag.  try the new code

Comment: I'm not sure I get how to query the database for my list in MVC? I added the GET for my Create() in the Controller to my initial post.

Comment: I changed my edit to use your code.  since you have 2 drop downs you should have 2 "selected" fields in your model.  in my example the selected value of the drop down will be passed back to the controller in the MemberOrgId field.  I don't know if that is the field you want the selected value to go into and not sure what field you want for the other drop down

Comment: Just to be safe, I cleared out my database and my migrations and performed a new InitialCreate. I updated the database, THEN I added everything as you specified in your EDIT. However, when I try to run now, I get an inner exception on my HomeController: `Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 6:No mapping specified for properties Users.OrganizationList, Users.SponsorList in Set Users.\r\nAn Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:\r\n  Entity is type [PROJECT.DAL.Users]`?

Comment: with this new SelectList(db.MemberOrganizations, "Id", "Name"); you are mapping the database result to a select list.  sounds to me like there is an issue there.  if you have another way of getting the data from there I would call that without the mapping and then loop through it in a foreach and add it to a list<selectlistitem>

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyModel
{
   public MyModel()
    {
        this.myDDLList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }   
    public List<SelectListItem> myDDLList { get; set; }
    public int ddlID { get; set; }
} 

public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyModel model = new MyModel();          

        using (YourEntities context = new YourEntities())
        {
            var list = context.YourTable.ToList();                 

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                model.myDDLList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item.NameField, Value = item.ValueField.ToString() });
            }              
        }

        return View(model);
    }


@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ddlID, Model.myDDLList)
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by using `ViewData[]` to pass a pre-filled select list from my controller to my view:

```
    // GET: /Admin/
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.headerTitle = "Create a User";
        ViewData["Organization"] = new SelectList(db.MemberOrganizations, "Id", "Name");
        ViewData["Sponsor"] = new SelectList(db.SponsorOrganizations, "Id", "Name");
        Users newUser = new Users();
        newUser.RegisteredDate = DateTime.Now;
        newUser.LastVisitDate = DateTime.Now;
        newUser.ProfilePictureSrc = null;
        return View(newUser);
    }
```

and then in my view simply read in the `ViewData[]` values into my `Html.DropDownList`'s as separate `SelectList`'s:

```
@Html.DropDownList("MemberOrgId", ViewData["Organization"] as SelectList, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "MemberOrgId" })
@Html.DropDownList("SponsorOrgId", ViewData["Sponsor"] as SelectList, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SponsorOrgId" })
```